# Using "Generation" to describe a process of generating

Tags: word-usage

Is is acceptable to use the word generation in the following context:

> The password generation process

Even if it is technically correct, is the word used like this contemporarily?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the complete sentence, or perhaps more.

Comment: A Google search for << "generation process" -lead >> gives a wide variety of examples of "X generation process", and a dictionary will give the relevant sense of 'generation' being used.

Comment: It isn't really different from, say, "power generation".  Yes, that's standard, contemporary use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As both a software developer and avid gamer, "generation" is a well established term to mean "automatically created".

- Procedural generation = building a game from randomized elements
- Password generation = letting the system generate a (random) password for you.
- File generation = having an application create a file for you (usually based on a template). E.g. an application that creates wedding invites based on a list of invitees.

From this, I extrapolate that "generation" is the correct terminology when referring to the *automated* creation of an item.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generation) agrees with me (emphasis is mine):

> 2
>   **a** :  the action or process of producing offspring :  procreation
>   **b** :  the process of coming or bringing into being generation of income
>   **c** :  **origination by a generating process :  production**; especially :  formation of a geometric figure by motion of another

---

> Even if it is technically correct, is the word used like this contemporarily?

If anything, I'd say the word is used more often than it was previously, due to the increase in software usage both in corporate and private environments.